# Shared test DB across Django TestCase

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-tests

**Intro**

I'm writing unit tests for a Django project where some DB entries are loaded from a file. It's expensive to parse the file and create all the entries.

The application has different modules to tests, so I'm implementing one `TestCase` per module.

**Issue**

The modules rely on the data parsed from the file *(ie. they need the same DB)*, but I can't afford re-setting up the DB for all the different `TestCase`, like here:

```
class TestBehavior_A(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        expensive_db_init()

class TestBehavior_B(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        expensive_db_init()

class TestBehavior_C(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        expensive_db_init()
```

Nor I can merge all my test cases in the the same class, otherwise it would be a mess.

**Ideally**

I would like to have one setup shared across all my tests cases *(ie. call `setUpClass` only once)*

Having something similar to that:

```
class TestBase(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        expensive_db_init()

   class TestBehavior_A(TestCase):
       pass

   class TestBehavior_B(TestCase):
       pass

   class TestBehavior_C(TestCase):
       pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any proper way to set-up the DB one time for all the `TestCase`.

Instead, I just check in `expensive_db_init()` if the DB has already been initialized from the file *(by checking the existence of certain entries)*, if not, I initialize it.

Answer (score -1):

Library Module: unittest

subleases from django.test.TestCase, which is subclass of unittest.TestCase.

```
from django.test import TestCase

from myapp.models import Animal

class AnimalTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        Animal.objects.create(name="lion", sound="roar")
        Animal.objects.create(name="cat", sound="meow")

    def test_animals_can_speak(self):
        """Animals that can speak are correctly identified"""
        lion = Animal.objects.get(name="lion")
        cat = Animal.objects.get(name="cat")
        self.assertEqual(lion.speak(), 'The lion says "roar"')
        self.assertEqual(cat.speak(), 'The cat says "meow"')
```

Running Tests:

run them using the test command of your project’s manage.py utility:

```
 $ ./manage.py test
```

## Run all the tests in the animals.tests module

```
$ ./manage.py test animals.tests
```

## Run all the tests found within the 'animals' package

```
$ ./manage.py test animals
```

## Run just one test case

```
$ ./manage.py test animals.tests.AnimalTestCase
```

## Run just one test method

```
$ ./manage.py test animals.tests.AnimalTestCase.test_animals_can_speak
```

Comment: This look like a copypaste from the documentation. Doesn't answer the question.